Prevent and stop clicks on connectors and endpoints with jsPlumb
with jsPlumb 2.12.6, I need prevent and stop all mouse events(click, dblclick,....) when clicking on connectors and endpoints.
I have tried many options and chatGPT as well, but no success.
My latest option was the next, but it didn't work:
const cc = jsPlumb.getConnections();
for (const item of cc) {
  item.connector.unbind("click");
  item.connector.unbind("dblclick");
  const endpoints = item.endpoints;
  for (const el of endpoints) {
    el.unbind("click");
    el.unbind("dblclick");
  }
}

